# Get rid of the transparency of a progress bar control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-xp, progress-bar

While there are several questions about how to make a WinForms [`ProgressBar` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6ak4h9.aspx) transparent, I am facing the opposite:

[image: Progress bar under Windows XP]

I.e. I am having a WinForms form (called from an [Add-in Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/) Outlook add-in) that contains a progress bar.

On Windows 7, everything looks fine, but on Windows XP, the progress bar's background seems to shine through (as you can see in the screenshot).

One special thing is that the [`FormBorderStyle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) of the form is set to `None`.

**My question is:**

Does anyone know the reason for this (unwanted) transparency and how to get rid of it?

**Update/solution:**

Thanks to [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622440/get-rid-of-the-transparency-of-a-progress-bar-control#comment17018342_12622440) I figured out that the form's [`TransparencyKey` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey.aspx) was set to some strange value. After clearing it altogether, it works like a charm:

[image: Correct display]

Comment: Check the transparency key on your form.  Try setting it to magenta or something off the wall if it is set to a color.

Comment: @JohnKoerner Bam! That was the solution, Thanks! And I even didn't know, such a property exists! Would you mind posting this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transparency key is set to the background color of the control.  Change it to a color you will not use, such as magenta.